# Ldap Unit Test Mock NamingEnumeration

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-ldap

I'm having trouble trying to mock the NamingEnumeration. Also, I cannot get the coverage to go inside of the lambda expression. I also cannot get the coverage inside of the while loop. When I run a unit test through the methods, coverage only shows through the `ldapTemplate.search` and it skips what's inside the lambda expression and it goes through the return list. I tried adding the Mock annotation to the NamingEnumeration and Attribute objects. The while loop seem to think NamingEnumeration  is empty, because of the no coverage.

The following results in 'Unnecessary stubbings detected in test class': `doReturn(true,false).when(enumeration).hasMore();` and `doReturn(attr).when(enumeration).next();`

**This is my Ldap method**

```
public List<MyObject> ldapQueryList(final String ldapSearch, final String key) {
        List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

        ldapTemplate.search("ou=User Accounts", "cn=" + ldapSearch), (Attributes attrs) -> {
                NamingEnumeration<?> enumeration = attrs.get(key).getAll();
                list.addAll(addToList(enumeration));
                return attrs;
        });

        return list;
    }
    public List<MyObject> addToList(NamingEnumeration<?> enumeration) throws NamingException {
        List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            final MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
            final String str = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
            myObj.setMyString(str);
            list.add(myObj);    
        }
        enumeration.close();
        return list;
    }
```

**This is the Unit Test**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LdapQueryDaoTest {
    @Mock
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;
    @InjectMocks
    private LdapDao ldapDao;
    @Mock 
    private NamingEnumeration<?> enumeration;
    @Mock 
    private Attribute attr;
    @Test
    public void ldapQueryList() throws DataAcesExcp, NamingException {
        List<String> searchResult = Collections.singletonList("search result");
        when(ldapTemplate.search( Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<AttributesMapper<String>> any())).thenReturn(searchResult);
        List<EmployeeVo> responseEntity = ldapDao.ldapQueryList(Const.EMPLOYEE_ID, "myLdapObj");
        Assert.assertNotNull(responseEntity);
    }
    @Test
    public void addToList() throws NamingException {
        doReturn(true,false).when(enumeration).hasMore();
        doReturn(attr).when(enumeration).next();
        Assert.assertNotNull(ldapQueryDaoImpl.addToList(enumeration));
    }
}
```

Comment: @second Thanks for the reply. I fixed that not I am seeing a different error `java.lang.ClassCastException: codegen.javax.naming.directory.Attributes$MockitoMock$1194996702 cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: I think I fixed it, it should have returned a string

Comment: You're reffering to `doReturn(attr).when(enumeration).next();` Yeah that is the wrong type, I missed that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having trouble trying to mock the NamingEnumeration.

Consider using a real enumeration instead. Basically you should only mock objects that are to complex to create yourself (Lists, Iterators and Enumeration are examples for things that are not).

> Also, I cannot get the coverage to go inside of the lambda expression.

It works as expected. You mocked (read replaced) the search method, so there is no evaluation of the lambda expression as it already has a defined result.

> The while loop seem to think NamingEnumeration is empty, because of the no coverage.
>
> The following results in 'Unnecessary stubbings detected in test class':
> doReturn(true,false).when(enumeration).hasMore(); and
> doReturn(attr).when(enumeration).next();

hasMore and next are typos on your end as the methods called in your example that are called are hasMoreElements and nextElement.

```
@Test
public void addToList() throws NamingException {
   doReturn(true,false).when(enumeration).hasMoreElements();
   doReturn(attr).when(enumeration).nextElement();
   Assert.assertNotNull(ldapQueryDaoImpl.addToList(enumeration));
}
```

---

You could verify the lambda expression seperately, example see below:

```
class MyMatcher implements AttributesMapper<Attributes> {

    List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Attributes mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) {

        NamingEnumeration<?> enumeration = attrs.get(key).getAll();
        list.addAll(addToList(enumeration));
        return attrs;
    }
}
```

```
public void test() {

  NamingEnumeration<? extends Attribute> enumeration = ...

  Attribute attributeMock = mock(Attribute.class);
  when(attributeMock.getAll()).thenReturn(enumeration);

  Attributes attributesMock = mock(Attributes.class);
  when(attributesMock.get(any(String.class)).thenReturn(attributeMock);

  MyMatcher matcher = new MyMatcher();
  matcher.mapFromAttributes(attr);

  // assert ... matcher.list
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see what you're saying. I only need the coverage now inside the Lambda expression. I removed the when on the ldapTemplate.search and I instead tried to give a mock value to `NamingEnumeration<?> enumeration = attrs.get(key).getAll();`but I cannot find the right thenReturn on the when. I've tried this:` when(attr.get(Mockito.anyString()).getAll()).thenReturn(enumeration);` and I get `The method thenReturn(NamingEnumeration<capture#1-of ?>) in the type OngoingStubbing<NamingEnumeration<capture#1-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (NamingEnumeration<capture#3-of ?>

Comment: You could move the lambda expression to a different method and just test it seperately. (Or just implement the `AttributesMapper` interface in an inner class and do tests on that one)

Comment: I might have the same problem because I cannot give a result to attr.get(Mockito.anyString()).getAll()

Comment: I've added some freestyle code (untested, might not compile) for the test of your lambda expression. You should get the idea.

Comment: Actually that test could replace both your tests, as there isn't anything left that can be covered here: The remaining thing would be the ldap search query syntax.